# Deploying ASP.NET Web API with EF Database-First Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a project I was working on for two months,

It contains three layers (Projects) :

1. Data Access Layer (C# Folder) (Containing The entity framework files).
2. Business Logic (C# Folder) (Containing The methods to manipulate data).
3. API (Web App) (Containing The API only calling the right methods of business layer).

I purchased a windows host that supports IIS 8 , and tried two ways to upload the project

First one : I Right clicked the API Layer and selected publish, then by FTP and gave it the correct data, then waited for it to upload, After finishing : when I try to call any method in any of the connectors it gives me (500 Internal Server Error).

Second one : Just copied all the files and putted it in my site, For shore won't work!

Keep in mind:

Its my first time working on Visual Studio, The database I already uploaded to my web site then debugged the solution locally and its working fine!.

Please help me.

Comment: Do you update the connection string after deploying?

Comment: I'd recommend to add some logging to your project. ELMAH is *the* tool for this. Internal server error usually means that some exception bubbles up from the application, which is easy to solve when you know which one it is. Of course the IIS event log should also show this information. As Wiktor said, a wrong connection string is a likely suspect.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I don't have to I think, Because my project is a Database First, Do I need to ? , Thank you for answering .

Comment: @GertArnold I'm in a shared host, so they didn't give me any options for logging or any thing, can I do it while i'm a hosted site, thank you for answering, I'll search about the tool you gave me.

Comment: @iYazee6: you have to, the database name could possibly remain the same but the database server is different.

Comment: @WiktorZychla But when I was working on the visual studio I was working on a remote database on the website, I didn't put it locally, should I change any thing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For who ever had a similar problem,

I think my problem is because I used a mysql database, and I have some columns that store date and time, and they just don't work together !

still my application is under development.